# Repeat HEAD until file exists

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, http-headers

I am using jQuery to upload a file and then periodically check the URL until the file is there.

I am uploading multiple files and on the server I have a script to zip them up and place them at a predetermined URL.

```
var processingZipFileCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
             $.ajax({
             url: https://server/file.zip,
             type: "HEAD",
             error: function() {
               console.log("File does not exist");
             },
             cache: false,
             success: function() {
               clearInterval(processingZipFileCheckInterval);
               console.log('File Processed');
             }
           });
         }, 3000);
```

However I always get a 403, even when the file exists. 
I think that Chrome is caching the initial 403 response because when I go to the link in the browser the HEAD command suddenly sees it as a 200 response and outputs 'File Processed' in the console.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: `403` means "forbidden", not "not found"

Comment: I should have said I am uploading the files to S3 and accessing via Cloudfront which is returning a 403. Not sure if I can change this behaviour.

Comment: It's not very clear but .. If it's caching, can you try adding `cache: false,` to your ajax !

Comment: Euh .. if it's S3 then I guess you have to make your file public so the ajax can get it (to bypass your 403) .. it's just quick thinking (https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/how-allow-public-access-amazon-bucket/)